# Hostname in socket server

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, hostname

I'm using the nodejs library:

```
import net from 'net'
```

When creating a server via:

```
net.createServer
```

Then I can make the server listen using the next procedure:

```
server.listen({host: 'localhost', port: 8000, exclusive: true}, () => etc..)
```

My question is why do I need to specify a host for the server? I mean, I should not always be serving on the server/ip where the service is placed? When I deploy a service in spring or nginx I don't have to specify the actual host since it's assumed what host should use. Isn't it right?

Comment: It is because you can listen at (i) `127.0.0.1`, meaning you will only accept connections from within the local host, or (ii) any of the actual IP addresses of your host, meaning you will only accept connections from the same LAN they are connected to, or (iii) `0.0.0.0`, meaning you will accept connections from anywhere, and the API is giving you the choice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you do not need to specify a host when deploying your server. It is an optional dependency for people who may be using a VPN and have 2 different IP addresses.
The following code is all you need to deploy your web server.

```js
server.listen(port, function() {
    // Do something
});
```